# entry/exit decorator for async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

How may I write an equivalent decorator/wrapper for `async` functions, which will log when the async **completes** (`return`s or `raise`s), without simply making it synchronous by `await`ing it.

```py
import functools

def trace_entry_exit(func):
    """non asyncio decorator"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("entry")
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("returned")  ### if func is async, this will print ~immediately
        except Exception as ex:
            print("raised")
            raise
        return result ### without awaiting func(), this will simply return the awaitable object ~immediately

    return wrapper
```

I'd like `returned` or `raised` to only print when the function returns (or raises), but **not** block on the call in the decorator.

The same would apply to anything wrapping `func`, except the decorator use case is unique in that it's expected to be ~transparent to both `func` body, and whoever *calls* `func()`, as it is/was in the non-async case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your wrapper `async`. Then you can `await` the function, and it will work just like the wrapped function but with the `print` after it finishes:

```py
import functools

def trace_entry_exit(func):
    """asyncio decorator"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("entry")
        try:
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("returned")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("raised")
            raise
        return result ### without awaiting func(), this will simply return the awaitable object ~immediately

    return wrapper
```

If you want it to work for either a coroutine or a synchronous function:

```py
import functools
import asyncio

def trace_entry_exit(func):
    """asyncio or not decorator"""
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("entry")
            try:
                result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
                print("returned")
            except Exception as ex:
                print("raised")
                raise
            return result
        return wrapper
    else:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("entry")
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print("returned")
            except Exception as ex:
                print("raised")
                raise
            return result
        return wrapper
```